# How does html/javascript know an attribute is a boolean and not a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following tag:

```
<a href="#;" data-is_male="true">Male</a>
<a href="#;" data-is_male="false">Female</a>
```

---

```
var isMale = $(this).data('is_male');
```

How does javascript know that the value true is a `boolean` and not a `string`?

Comment: @VladislavLadicky But with [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), "Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)."

Comment: Ahh, it's jQuery. Then, JavaScript doesn't know nothing. Anything returned in dataset is string, but jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain JS does not parse "false" as false, "true" is truthy so it could conceivably end up as 1

jQuery however parses the data-attribute as boolean for true/false strings

```js
console.log(typeof document.querySelector("[data-is_male]").getAttribute("data-is_male"))

console.log(typeof $("[data-is_male]").data("is_male"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#;" data-is_male="true">Male</a>
<a href="#;" data-is_male="false">Female</a>
```

This is because of this jQuery code

```js
function getData(data) {
  if (data === "true") {
    return true;
  }

  if (data === "false") {
    return false;
  }

  if (data === "null") {
    return null;
  }

  // Only convert to a number if it doesn't change the string
  if (data === +data + "") {
    return +data;
  }

  if (rbrace.test(data)) {
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }

  return data;
}
```

Additional information from @connexo

The browser does know what it is - because it is always a `String`. A few built-in `Boolean` attributes exist, such as `disabled` or `readonly` or `checked` on form input elements, but these work differently:

Built-in boolean attributes are reflected as a same-name property on the element object and return true as soon as the element **has** the attribute, **independent of the value assigned to the attribute**. Vice versa, if you set the property on the element, it does automatically get the attribute (with an empty `String` as value) [`checked` being the exception, this is one-way].

Check this snippet:

```html
<input type="text" disabled="false" />
```

The input is disabled even though the value `false` seems to suggest that it is not disabled.

It has to be said that the above is invalid HTML because the specification allows only two values for each Boolean attribute: The empty `String`

```
disabled=""
```

and the name of the Boolean attribute itself

```
disabled="disabled"
```

Comment: Feel free to delete my edit if you think it doesn't add value.

Comment: Please read my part and consider upgrading your answer as I think it will help future readers.

Comment: Interestingly this resulted in a downvote - the dupe is from 2011

Comment: a dupe is a dupe is a dupe. This functionality hasn't changed since 2011

Comment: If it makes you feel good. By all means

Comment: Code in 1.6 `data = data === "true" ? true :
    data === "false" ? false :
    data === "null" ? null ` - same result, different code

Comment: @mplungjan My upvote you've got :D